# select2 required false jquery not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I use jQuery to make select2's required field false? Using jQuery, I want to make each and every select2 require = fasle and disabled it.

I try this...... but $('#accodeformheader').find('input, select').attr('required', false); is not working.
Any solution to make "required" = false for select2 ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#idtask').change(function() {
                  var taskVal = $(this).val();
                  console.log("Current task value", taskVal);
                  if (taskVal === "Grass
                    // $('#idspeakerdetailsdiv').display="block";
                    document.getElementById("idspeakerdetailsdiv").style.display = "block";
                  }
                  else {
                    // if ($('#idspeakerdetailsdiv').display=="block") {
                    // $('#idspeakerdetailsdiv').display="none";
                    document.getElementById("idspeakerdetailsdiv").style.display = "none";
                    // }
                  }
                })

                $('.lexemeview').click(function() {
                  $('#accodeformheader').find('input, select').attr('disabled', true);
                  $('#accodeformheader').find('input, select').attr('required', false);
                  
                  document.getElementById("accodeformheader").style.display = "none";
                  
                  buttonType = $(this).attr("id")
                  activeform(buttonType)
                  $('#formdisplay').find('input, select').attr('disabled', true);
                  $('#editbutton').attr('hidden', false);
                  // $('#idname').attr('hidden', true);
                  // $('#idage').attr('hidden', true);
                  
                  // sending accesscode using AJAX
                  // getting speaker details assigned to that accesscode
              
                  var accode = $(this).attr("id");
                  console.log(accode)
                  $.getJSON("{{url_for('karya_bp.getonespeakerdetails')}}", {
                    asycaccesscode:String(accode)
                    }, function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        metadata = data.speakerdetails.current.workerMetadata
                        console.log (metadata)
                        // accesscode = data.speakerdetails.accesscode
                        $('#accesscode').attr('value', accode)
```

```
<div id="accodeformheader" style="display: block;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idaccesscodefor">Access Code For:</label><br>                           
                <select class="accesscodefor" id="idaccesscodefor" name="accesscodefor" style="width:55%" required></select><br>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idtask">Task :</label><br>                           
                <select class="task" id="idtask" name="task"  style="width:55%" required></select><br>
              </div>

             <div id="uploadaccode" style="display: block;"></div> 
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <!-- return render_template('homespeaker.html', data = table_data, speaker_data_accesscode= speaker_data_accesscode, speaker_data_name = speaker_data_name, 
                                                              speaker_data_age =speaker_data_age, speaker_data_gender=speaker_data_gender) -->
                <label class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idname" name="sname" placeholder="--Speaker Name--" style="width:55%" value="" required >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sagegroup">Age Group: </label> <br> 
              <select class="age" id="idage" name="sagegroup" style="width:55%" required>
              <!-- <div id="ageoptions"></div> -->
              </select><br>
                </div>

            <div id="idspeakerdetailsdiv" style="display: none;">
                <div class="form-group">                    
                <label for="sgender">Gender: </label>  <br>
                <select class="gender" id="idgender" name="sgender" style="width:55%" required>
                  <!-- <div id="genderoptions"></div> -->
                
                </select><br>

                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="educationalevel">Educational Level: </label> <br>
                <select class="educationlvl" id="idelevel" name="educationalevel" style="width:55%" required>
                </select><br>
                </div>
              

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="moe12">Medium Of Education (upto 12ᵗʰ): </label><br>                           
                    <select class="educationmediumupto12" id="idmediumpre" name="moe12" multiple="multiple" style="width:55%" required>
                    </select><br>
                </div> 
                
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="moea12">Medium Of Education (After 12ᵗʰ): </label><br>                           
                    <select class="educationmediumafter12" id="idmediumpost" name="moea12" multiple="multiple" style="width:55%" required>
                    </select><br>
                </div> 
                
                

          </div>


            <button type="button" id="closebutton" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br><br>
            
            </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: Post html as well to reproduce it.

Comment: There are errors in your JS code and I can see its not full code. Please check and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove "required" property if you don't need

```
$('select').removeAttr('required');
```

If you want to set again do as follows:

```
$('select').prop('required', 'required');
```

if you want to remove for particular select2 dropdown based on id or class as follows:

```
$('#your_id_name').removeAttr('required');
```

**With Class Name:**

```
$('.your_class_name').removeAttr('required');
```

Similarly you can set based on ids and classes as follows:

```
$('#your_id_name').prop('required', 'required');
```

**With Class Name:**

```
$('.your_class_name').prop('required', 'required');
```

I hope i got your question right and answered correctly.